# Trying to achieve desired output of KML in R as seen in GIS software. Not sure what the problem is

Tags: r, kml, xml, kmz

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
library(maps)
world_map_data <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
state_map_data <- map('state', fill = TRUE, plot = FALSE) %>% st_as_sf()
hail <- st_read("HA_2020-05-24.kml")

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = hail) +
  theme(legend.position="none")+coord_sf(xlim = c(-104, -99), ylim = c(31,33))
```

The code above produces an output such as
[image]

And the associated data frame for Hail looks like this

```
      Name Description                       geometry
1 41710661             POLYGON ((-99.79714 36.5170...
2 41710662             POLYGON ((-100.0323 36.3466...
3 41710663             POLYGON ((-100.2621 36.1391...
4 41710664             POLYGON ((-100.0632 36.2512...
5 41710665             POLYGON ((-98.9919 36.20685...
6 41710668             POLYGON ((-101.0609 35.4591...
```

The desired output for the hail KML is
[image]

I am trying to figure how to get the same colored contours for the R output as the ones in the ArcMap Output. There is a reporting portion to these images hence why I am using R for it's rmarkdown capabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, just need to pass a `fill` argument to `aes` and a color scheme:

```r
library(sf)
library(terra)

r <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))
template <- disagg(rast(r), 10)
rr <- resample(r, template)
rr <- floor(rr/100) * 100
v <- as.polygons(rr)


v_sf = st_as_sf(v)

# in your case, fill = Name
ggplot(v_sf, aes(fill = elevation)) + geom_sf(color = NA) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "yellow", high = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: So I thought that was the case but name is a discrete value though.

Comment: `as.numeric(Name)` should do

Comment: You're right man. I should I known that bit.